# Удалить неизвестные символы

Tags: c#

Программа берет из реестра значение ключа, но в полученной строке есть неизвестные символы, которые мешают правильной обработки строк. Сама программа при этом, в обычных Label не отображает эти символы.

Например, программа получила строку и в файле лога:

[image: строка в файле лога]

На веб странице:

[image: та же строка на веб странице]

И мне нужно как-то обрезать всё начиная с nul. Как это сделать?

Comment: Возможно это вам поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1522884/remove-all-non-ascii-characters-from-string/14145356

Comment: @trydex это было полезно, но не помогло. Может вы знаете как можно обрезать всё начиная с nul?
Что-то типа `string.Remove(string.IndexOf(nul))` но я не знаю какой код у символа nul.

Comment: @DezMax идете по строке, ищете когда будет попадание по 0x00(str[i] == '0x00'. Далее получаете позицию символа NUL и делаете str.Split().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string.Remove(string.IndexOf("\x00"));`